# 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'subtract'

Tags: python, dataframe, typeerror, attributeerror

I have a dataframe that is a combination of values from a few different list. There is a column in this Dataframe with labels corresponding to the list that each value came from.

I want to subtract two columns in the dataframe and have them grouped by the label column.

I originally tried simply grouping them and subtracting them

```
HvL=df.groupby('Label')['High']-df.groupby('Label')['Low']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'

HvL=df.groupby('Label')['High'].subtract(df['Low'], fill_value=0)
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'subtract'
```

I ended up subtracting them then using .index to add the Label column as the index

```
HvL.index=df['Label']
HvL1=HvL.sort_values(ascending=False)
```

This  worked, but I was wondering if there was a way to subtract them while they were already grouped into the columns similar to my first two attempts.

Like this:

```
label|   0
---------------
 AA  |0.610001
 ZTS |0.03
 THC |0.79
```

Comment: `HvL=df.groupby('Label').apply(lambda x: x['High']-x['Low'])`?

Comment: Thanks this was pretty close to what I wanted, only problem is that the output gives both the column for the Label and Index separately. I wanted the Label column to be the index, I apologize if I didn't word that out clearly.

Comment: `HvL=df.groupby('Label').apply(lambda x: x['High']-x['Low']).droplevel(1)`?

Comment: This worked, Thank you.

Comment: the above will give you Series If you want dataframe then chain `reset_index()` to it

Comment: I did intend to get a Series, I appreciate the tip though.